# Woocommerce after product update get stock

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a problem with adding action to 'save_post_product' hook.
I want to send stock data to my external API when product is changed(updated) in woocommerce admin.

The problem is that the stock values i get from simple product after the action is called are one 'iteration' old. By that i mean that the stock data i get seem to be the data before update. so if i call the update product 2 times, first time i get old data, second time i get the new ones.

```
add_action('save_post_product', array($this, 'product_changed'), 99, 3);
function product_changed($post_id, $post, $update)
    {
        if ('product' != $post->post_type || $update != true) {
            return;
        }
        $_pf = new WC_Product_Factory();
        $product = $_pf->get_product($post_id);
        $items = array();
        if ($product->product_type == 'simple') {
            $product->get_total_stock();
            $inStock = $product->is_in_stock();
            $qty = $product->get_stock_quantity();
            $managing = $product->managing_stock();
            $items[$product->id] = [
                ...
            ];
        } elseif ($product->product_type == 'variable') {
            $variations = $product->get_available_variations();
            /*For variations it works properly*/
            }
        }
        $itemsJson = json_encode($items);
        $this->sendData($itemsJson, '/products-changed/');    
    }
```

TLDR (example):

Lets say that product is set to manage stock, stock quantity 500 and is in stock.

Now i change the product not to manage stock, and set that it is out of stock.
I hit update.
Everything runs and wordpress gets to my code. When i get the values i still get

```
$product->is_in_stock(); //true
$product->get_stock_quantity(); //500
$product->managing_stock(); //yes
```

Now, when i hit the update again, everything runs the second time, but now i get the correct values.

```
$product->is_in_stock(); //false
$product->get_stock_quantity(); //0
$product->managing_stock(); //no
```

I assume that the product stock update runs after 'save_post_product' hook however, i was not able to find any other hook that might solve my problem.

NOTE: It works well with variations in the first 'iteration'. I think it has to do something with the $product->get_available_variations() code.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like hooking the action to `wp_insert_post` hook did the trick :

```
add_action('wp_insert_post', array($this, 'product_changed'), 99, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

`save_post` is triggered BEFORE the update. So you would have to use the $_POST, $_GET or the global $post_data, as specified in https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post

You already resolved this by using `wp_insert_post`, so that's okay. Just a clarification for any one seeing this